# Is DNS hacking for unit testing code with HTTP connections possible or sensible?

Tags: networking, dns

Is there a sensible way to hijack DNS in a limited way to mock outgoing HTTP connections, with a local test server?

The idea is that the code would execute just the same way it normally would, but the request would get redirected to some local test server returning mock responses instead.

I know this can be done by having a set of test configurations so that the requested URI is localhost instead, but I find that causes a plethora of issues, with the most common being devs forgetting to uncomment the production config or getting confused about setting the test config.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds too much like an SO question. I think it belongs here since it is specifically about whether altering DNS resolution behavior is a good thing or possible at all, not the code to do it

Comment: Is it possible, yes, it’s possible that’s why DNS over HTTPS (DoH) exists.

Comment: Huh. This is a little ironic to read with the PiHole on my desk. Now, I need to figure out how to do this nicely without the OS throwing any fits about some random code trying to misbehave

Comment: Pro tip, most build systems provide some form of configuration substitution/transformation capability. I strongly recommend you look into how you can store all your configuration documents in version control and transform them at build for whatever environment. this is common to most CICD platforms.

Comment: You are right. I really, really dislike that pattern though, as a DevOps professional. A core tenet of CICD is removing as much of system configuration as possible from the development layer, and asking devs to include config per system and usually even config for test scenarios outside testing the config logic itself goes against that IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not touching the code to check is wise. So you're right to manipulate the environment to force the usage of a test server.

A DNS hack would affect the whole network, possibly irritating other tests that aim to the same service.

To minimize the impact, the simplest way to reroute the network traffic to the test server would be to configure the `hosts` file *at the client* where the software to test is installed.

```
# Linux:
/etc/hosts

# Windows:
%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Just map the IP of the test system to the DNS-name(s) of the production server(s):

```
# IP of the test server:
192.168.10.20   prod.server.com prod2.server.com
192.168.10.20   prod prod2      # if prod-servers are part of the local network.
```

To resolve the server name the system will first check the `hosts` file. Then, if not successful will follow the DNS request.

It might be a good idea to clear the DNS cache after the reconfiguration:

```
# Linux:
resolvectl flush-caches

# Windows:
ipconfig /flushdns
```

For this (or any DNS solution) you have to be sure the software does not code the IP-address of the production server anywhere. (Perhaps disconnect test-network from internet / production network?)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for -- server running at the same machine as client. Much appreciated!

Comment: If it served you, you should set the "solved" hook.

Comment: Oh duh \*facepalm\*. Got too excited and hit bookmark instead of accept :D